# Highcharts: Html table from csv

Tags: highcharts

I try to display an html table fill with datas from a csv file. Highcharts doc has no example with a csv file. Here is a sample of my code:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></div>
<h3>Exported CSV:</h3>
<pre id="preview"></pre>

<script>
var myCSV= 'http://myserver/csv/csv_file.csv';
var myChart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {type:'column'},
    data: {csvURL: myCSV},
    exporting: {showTable: true},
...
});
document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = myChart.getCSV();
</script>
```

Result: html table is empty.
Do I need to add and fill series option in myChart? How?
Is getCSV() the right method to call?

Comment: Hi @user3589732, It is working as expected in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vxjmsdk8/ Could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: Example is working because datas are inside the html tag, in my case I want to display content of a csv file with a known url.

Comment: my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thomasf/htyzmnLx/35/

Comment: cors policy blocks access to csv file url in jsfiddle. But I'll take any help outside of jsfiddle. Thx

Comment: Hello. The table is empty because data is loaded asynchronously. First, the chart is created and later data is recieved. You can use some chart event to wait for the data, but the csv structure seems to be invalid. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ky2v90bc/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The table is empty because data is loaded asynchronously. First, the chart is created and later data is recieved. Use some chart event to wait for the data.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69011256/edit) your answer and include the actual explanation given in the comment (also the jsfiddle code if it is relevant). Thank you.